# sql insertion and checking entering value not empty

Tags: mysql, sql, null

I have a insertion statement that will insert the values from text boxes. It working fine now i want to check the text box must not be empty by using sql query.

My insertion statement is like this:

```
INSERT INTO guestpasstypes(guestPasstype_Name)values('" + tbPassType.Text + "')"
```

Comment: Why in SQL query? is it not better to check in host language? And what should be the result of the query if it is empty? Should it ignore or give error?

Comment: it must give an error. I want to check using  query that is requirement

Comment: You're inviting SQL injection by appending what the user types to your code. What if the user typed "password; drop table users" or something similar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also agree that you should avoid calling that SQL, due to the potential for injection attacks, but if for some reason, your really need to do it, then this should do the trick:

```
"INSERT INTO guestpasstypes(guestPasstype_Name)
  select '" + tbPassType.Text + "' from dual where '" + tbPassType.Text + "' <> '';"
```

Answer (score 1):

Use whatever language that you using to get the text from the text box to see if it's empty or null.  Most languages have these checks.  (ex: php; isempty())  Also, if you don't want spaces, use trim as well.

Answer (score 1):

Make guestPasstype_Name to be NOT NULL and ensure that MySQL runs in SQL conformance mode. Following might work:

```
INSERT INTO guestpasstypes(guestPasstype_Name)values(
    IF('" + tbPassType.Text + "'='', NULL,'" + tbPassType.Text+"')"
```

Answer (score 1):

I can see two solutions

- Check 'tbPassType.Text' before you generate sql query (recommended)
- Create check constraint in the 'guestpasstypes' table like this:

  ALTER TABLE dbo.guestpasstypes ADD CONSTRAINT
      CK_guestPasstype_Name CHECK ((LEN(guestPasstype_Name])>(0)))

(the given example is for MSSQL but I hope MySQL has constrainrs too)